# How to create an eventarc trigger in terraform for GCS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-storage, event-arc

I would like to create an eventarc trigger for GCS object creation. According to the Eventarc documentation, this should use the direct GCS trigger. I can create it like this, but I don't know where to put the bucket name:

```
resource "google_eventarc_trigger" "upload" {
  name     = "upload"
  location = "europe-west1"
  matching_criteria {
    attribute = "type"
    value     = "google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized"
  }
  destination {
    workflow = google_workflows_workflow.process_file.id
  }
  service_account = google_service_account.workflow.email
}
```

When I run this example, I get the following error:

```
Error: Error creating Trigger: googleapi: Error 400: The request was invalid: The request was invalid: missing required attribute "bucket" in trigger.event_filters
```

Comment: What is the full error message showing line it fails?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reading the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/eventarc_trigger) didn't help, but after reading the [Creating Eventarc triggers with Terraform](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/creating-eventarc-triggers-terraform)
 blog post multiple times I found the answer. The `bucket` can be provided as another block of `matching_criteria` like this:

```
resource "google_eventarc_trigger" "upload" {
  name     = "upload"
  location = "europe-west1"
  matching_criteria {
    attribute = "type"
    value     = "google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized"
  }
  matching_criteria {
    attribute = "bucket"
    value     = google_storage_bucket.uploads.name
  }
  destination {
    workflow = google_workflows_workflow.process_file.id
  }
  service_account = google_service_account.workflow.email
}
```